# How can I join SQL Server tables in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a column named `LEADER` in 16 tables in my SQL Server database. I'd like to join all the tables to show the `Leader` column and the table it belongs to in my database

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select GroupLeaders.ID, Account.Leader, Engineers.Leader from GroupLeaders inner join Account on GroupLeaders.id = Account.Leader", conn);
```

Comment: Please remove the C# code and the [datagridview] tag if your question is about SQL Server. Show what you've tried and what was the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

SELECT 'Table1' AS Source, LEADER FROM Table1
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Table2' AS Source, LEADER FROM Table2
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Table3' AS Source, LEADER FROM Table3
UNION ALL

...

SELECT 'Table16' AS Source, LEADER FROM Table16

Note: Make sure to replace "Table1", "Table2", etc. with the actual names of your tables. Also, the LEADER column should be present in all 16 tables for this query to work.

Comment: Please, can you make a code to display it in DatagridView.....Am quite confused here.